# Paste a single row of data from one worksheet to another n number of times

Tags: excel, vba

I need to paste a single row of data from one worksheet to another `n` number of times. I want to take the input `n` through an input box.

Are there any pointers on how to do this using VBA?

Comment: Recording a macro is a good startpoint

Comment: This site is really not intended for wholescale code to be asked for like this; this is for specific questions only.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to understand the process and the places I could start with. Are such questions not allowed on this site? Could you please point me to any place you are aware of where this kind of questions should be directed to?

Comment: @user5241675 - Check out [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question.  The more you abide by this, the more we're all able to help!

Comment: @BruceWayne - Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bare bones macro.  Note you'll need to tweak the sheet names are required.

```
Sub test()
Dim dataWS As Worksheet, copyToWS As Worksheet
Dim copyRow&, noCopies&, copySheetLastRow&, i&

Set dataWS = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set copyToWS = Sheets("Sheet2") ' Change these as required.

copySheetLastRow = copyToWS.Cells(copyToWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If copySheetLastRow > 1 Then
 copySheetLastRow = copySheetLastRow + 1
End If


copyRow = InputBox("What row would you like to copy?")
noCopies = InputBox("How many times do you want it copied?")

For i = 1 To noCopies
    With dataWS
        copyToWS.Rows(copySheetLastRow).Value = .Rows(copyRow).Value
    End With

    copySheetLastRow = copyToWS.Cells(copyToWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

It takes the chosen Row from your data WS, and puts it in the next available row in your "copy to" worksheet.

Edit: Per your question, this code ensures that the sheet being copied to has the data put on the next available row (being the next empty row starting at row 1).

```
copySheetLastRow = copyToWS.Cells(copyToWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

This uses the `copyToWS` worksheet, and gets the last used row. `copyToWS.Rows.Count` counts the number of rows in the sheet, then looks to the next non-empty row (`.End(xlUp)`).  (This is equivalent at starting at the very last row, in column A, then hitting CTRL+[Up Arrow].

```
If copySheetLastRow > 1 Then
         copySheetLastRow = copySheetLastRow + 1
End If
```

If the last row is determined to be *greater than row 1*, then add a row to that, so it becomes # + 1.  This is because if the last row is row 1, that means there's no info. in the sheet yet.  If, however, the last row is determined to be 4, then that means there is data in row 4.  We add 1 to this number, so we don't overwrite the data in that row.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. Can you please explain what this part does?`code`                                                               copySheetLastRow = copyToWS.Cells(copyToWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If copySheetLastRow > 1 Then
 copySheetLastRow = copySheetLastRow + 1
End If

Comment: @user5241675 - I have edited the post to include a breakdown of that line.  Let me know if I can explain further!  Also, if it works as the answer, would you mind marking the post as such? Thanks!

Comment: It is great explanation. Thanks a lot. This is answered.

Comment: @user5241675 - glad to help! To mark as the answer, click the "check mark" to the left of my post.  Thanks!

Comment: I had another question.code If copySheetLastRow > 1 Then copySheetLastRow = copySheetLastRow + 1 End If code Say the last row gets incremented at the end of the for loop i.e. at codeIf copySheetLastRow > 1 Then copySheetLastRow = copySheetLastRow + 1 End If code , would the If statement increment the row number again? Say copySheetLastRow is 4, then it goes again to the If statement, and increments it to 5, because copySheetLastRow>1, or will copySheetLastRow remain as 4 till the next i increment happens?

Comment: @user5241675 - If I follow your question correctly, `copySheetLastRow` will remain 4 during the entire `For i = 1` loop, *until* it gets to the `copySheetLastRow = copyToWS.Cells(...` line, then it updates itself.

Comment: Thank you. What I am trying to ask is, say copySheetLastRow=4, will there be an increment that happens with the If condition or will the increment happen only within the loop and the If condition checked only once at the beginning of the code? code If copySheetLastRow > 1 Then
 copySheetLastRow = copySheetLastRow + 1
End If